# Run service using Repeat alarm in between particular time of Day

Tags: android

I have a service which runs on every 1 minute using repeat alarm. But I want to run this service in between 9.30 AM to 4 PM and 8 PM - 2.30 AM (timezone is Indian Standard Time-IST) only and run for every 1 minutes.

For example :

```
    UTC Time
StartTime   EndTime
22:00   05:00
23:50   06:12
00:00   06:00
01:00   09:00
01:00   05:30
01:15   08:00
01:20   08:00
01:30   07:00
02:30   09:00
03:00   09:30
03:45   10:00
04:00   09:00
06:00   15:00
07:00   14:25
07:00   15:00
07:00   21:00
07:30   15:30
07:55   16:35
08:00   16:30
9:00    15:00
13:00   20:00
14:00   20:00
07:30   10:30
```

How to run a Service for every 1 min in between the above UTC timings only? Should I use a Service to run on 24 hours and inside the service check condition to do logic or can I manage using repeat alarm itself?

Answer (score 0):

Cancel your alarmManager using the same intent that you used to create the alarmmanager ,when you want to stop the alarm.

Comment: then how to register an alarm for 8 PM. This time(8 PM) is not a constant one.It will vary based on user selected timezones.

Comment: This is how you create custom alarm.This will take the calander time of the phone :    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,27);
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
   cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
     intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),10000,
     pendingIntent);

Comment: Yes this code is Ok to register alarm when we know trigger time.But in my case,trigger time  will vary randomly from database. For example if alarm registered for 9 Am to 10 Am.Then next trigger time may come as 9.30 AM. So if i register another alarm for 9.30 AM,another service will create and it is duplicate of existing running service(9 AM to 10 AM)

Comment: then take the trigger time from database store it in a variable say x and call x.gettimeInMillis() for start time and for the gap in duration say, you want it after every 5 minutes,itt will be 30000, and lastly cancel the alarm when you want to.If you want to cancel your alarm after 1 hour of starting add x + 1 hour in millisecond to  cancel it.

Comment: I edited my Question above.I hope given example is easy to understand my context.